# C# perform action for every row in a dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach

[image: Form]

So I need to be able to convert each row of the Data grid separately with the xWMAEncode.exe program and how the xwmaEncode works is like this xwmaencode.exe InputFile OutputFile so like this would work xwmaencode.exe directorytofile\Filename.xwm directorytofile\Filename.wav

so I need a way to perform that CMD Command on each row as well as being able to specify the order it takes each cell in for example xwmaEncode.exe inputdirectory\Inputfilename.xwm outputdirectory\outputfilename.wav

+XWMAEncode is a Command prompt based program so it needs to run in a command prompt window

+I will also need to close all the cmd windows after they are done converting the file

But mainly I need to know how to start the for each loop for this

Comment: Have you tried anything? What exactly isn't working? You should specify a concrete question about a problem you're facing, not ask for someone to write the application for you.

Comment: I don't really know how to start a for each loop for that situation and im pretty new to C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont understand what you want to perform but for looping through the rows in datagridview you may do something like this

```
for(int i=0; i<dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
//do the row operation here...
}
```

For looping through and accessing each cell of all columns of data grid you should do this

```
for(int i=0; i<dataGridView.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   for(int j=0; j<dataGridView.ColumnCount; j++)
   {
      //dataGridView.Rows[i].Cells[j]; to access the cell and perform any other action on it
   }
 }
```

Comment: Im trying to use XwmaEncode on each row of the files grid. XwmaEncode syntax is xWMAEncode.exe <input File> <Output File>       So I need to be able to access each of the text box cells in the row and specify their location within the syntax of xWMAEncode.exe so for example I would need to do xwmaEncode.exe <Row1Cell2 + Row1Cell1 " " + Row1Cell3 + Row1Cell4>